# Best practice - Generic webdriverWait till loading popup exist, if error appears fail the test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, webdriver

My problem is I have customWaitMethods such as:

```
    public void waitForLoading(WebElement loadingElement, WebElement errorElement) {
    long timeOut = Long.parseLong(PropertyReader.getInstance().getProperty("DEFAULT_TIME_OUT"));
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver(), timeOut);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(loadingElement.toString())));

        if (errorElement.isDisplayed()) {
            throw new TestException();
        }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timed out after default time out");
    } catch (TestException e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected error occurred, environment error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need some generic customWait methods. I do a search, but several cases need to be handled. Error msg appear -> fail the test. wait for the loading content, and it disappeared, -> check the search result.

How can I extend this code if I would like to check continuously some error_message element appears as well and in this case I would throw an exception? So independently I can handle the timeout exception and the other, error msg?

This sript is failing because of the IF. ErrorElement does not appear on the page, ---> nosuchelementException

Answer (score 1):

You can `catch` different `Exception`s as you see fit. In your case, you want to `catch` the `TimeoutException` to handle time outs. Then `catch` a different type of exception to handle the error message:

```
public void waitForLoading() {
    long timeOut = Long.parseLong(...);
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(...);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(...));

        if (<error-message-appears>) {
            throw new CustomErrorMessageAppearedException();
        }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timed out after...");
    } catch (CustomErrorMessageAppearedException e) {
        // handle error message
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution because it is handling the error msg appears option as well. Thank you!

Comment: I need to ask something here. The problem is that, the test is failing with NoSuchElementException: <error-message-appears> It seems, if is not a good option here. any advice?

Comment: Not a good idea to un-accept an answer to ask another question. If you have another question, create a new question and reference this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I see is:

```
public void waitForLoading() {
        long timeOut = Long.parseLong(PropertyReader.getInstance().getProperty("DEFAULT_TIME_OUT"));
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver(), timeOut);
            if (!wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wait_element")));) 
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        } catch (TimeOutException e) {
            System.out.println("Timed out after " + timeOut + "seconds waiting for loading the results.");
        }
    }
```